# Check language in Orbeon using get method

Tags: get, orbeon

Is there some way to set language in orbeonBuilder using get method ? I mean I want use URL like: .../fr/orbeon/builder/new?lang=en to lead me to orbeonBuilder in English.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `?fr-language=en` (make sure to use `fr-language`, not `fr-lang` as I had incorrectly said before.)

Comment: Thank You for respone, but it is not working for me. I try: http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/new?fr-lang=en or http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/new?fr-lang=fr What can be wrong ?

Comment: Ok, I've done it. It is not fr-lang. It is: fr-language. regards